# R - Shapiro Test in dnorm() with weird p-value

Tags: r, normal-distribution, simulation

I'm trying to use `shapiro.test()` function in R to test if my data fits in a normal curve. For this, I'm looking to the p-value of the output, if it's bigger than 0.05, for example.

However, when I try a simple test with the `dnorm()`, it results in a p-value << 0.05, what means that my data doesn't represents a normal model.

This is the simple code that I used:

```r
x = seq(-5, 5, length.out = 100)
y = dnorm(x = x, mean = 0, sd = 1)
shapiro.test(y)
```

And I've got this result:

```r
Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  y
W = 0.73527, p-value = 3.887e-12
```

What's the problem about my test?

Comment: The problem is that the test should give me p-value > 0.05, because my data represents a normal distribution.

Comment: are you meant to be using `rnorm`?

Comment: Even `rnorm(x,0,1)` makes no sense, as most of the values of `x` are not natural numbers. I wonder what OP actually tried to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears there's a bit of confusion between `dnorm` and `rnorm`.

The first finds the density value for a distribution given some `x` values, these are the "heights", corresponding to each `x` values.

```
x = seq(-5, 5, length.out = 100)
y = dnorm(x = x, mean = 0, sd = 1)
```

So if we plot:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
plot(x,y) # notice I used both x and y
hist(y)
```

[image]

Notice that we get the `y` values of each `x` you passed, as you defined them.
But the frequency plot (`hist`) of these "heights" tells us a different story.

This is the problem, your frequencies are **not** normal.

---

Now, look the same plots for `rnorm()`, note that we don't define `x`, we just need to tell how many points (`n`) we want :

```
y_true = rnorm(n=100, 0, 1) # n defines how many points to simulate

par(mfrow=c(2,1))
plot(y_true)
hist(y_true)
```

[image]

Notice that now we have the frequencies following the classical bell-shaped curve (try with 1000 to see it more clear).

And the test works as expected:

```
shapiro.test(y_true)
# 
# Shapiro-Wilk normality test
# 
# data:  y_true
# W = 0.98818, p-value = 0.5219
```

Also, `dnorm()` is deterministic, you give `x,mean,sd` values and get the corresponding y value (following the Normal distribution function). Instead `rnorm()` is, in some way the opposite, you just need to define `mean` and `sd`, and it will simulate `n` "casual" numbers that will follow that distribution.

For additional pieces of information read [here](http://ww2.coastal.edu/kingw/statistics/R-tutorials/prob.html).

Comment: Thank you. I really could see the difference between them.